# How do I decrypt a text in a linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, encryption

I am doing a web page to display information from a database. The field I am displaying is encrypted and the query is LINQ using C#.

Below is the query:

```
    public IQueryable<JudgmentView> GetJudgmentReport([QueryString("id")] decimal? categoryId)
    {
        IQueryable<JudgmentView> query = db.JudgmentViews;
        if (categoryId.HasValue && categoryId > 0)
        {
            query = from p in db.JudgmentViews
                    where p.CaseId == categoryId
                    select p;
            return query;
        }
        return query;
    }
```

The data returned is being displayed in aspx page. I want to be able to decrypt the field contents before it is displayed on the page. How do I construct the query to be able to decrypt the field contents before it is displayed?

Comment: With Select() you can project a new object with _decrypted_ content. How...well it depends what your object actually is.

Comment: It depends on when and where you want your decrypted content. If it is only for webpage then you can just make a helper function that decrypts and output it's value to page. If you need it for some business logic then just go over your query results with foreach and decrypt.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a method in the `Select` statement like this:

```
var decryptQuery = db.JudgmentViews.Where(p => p.CaseId == categoryId)
                                   .Select(p => SomeMethodThatDecryptsView(p);
```

Then you'd need another method with a signature like

```
private notSureWhatToReturnHere SomeMethodThatDecryptsView(JudgmentView view)
```

I don't know what the output of your decryption method would be, so you may have to change the return type of your `GetJudgmentReport` method.

---

If you need to decrypt just one field, and assuming you can store the decrypted value in the same field, you could create new `JudgmentViews` instances on the fly, decrypting just that one field. (I'll use query syntax, like you originally used.)

```
query = (from p in db.JudgmentViews
         where p.CaseId == categoryId
         select new JudgmentView
         {
             FieldOne = p.FieldOne,
             FieldTwo = p.FieldTwo,
             ...
             JudgmentField = MethodToDecryptJudgmentField(p.JudgmentField)
         });
```

Comment: why not just `.Select(SomeMethodThatDecryptsView);`

Comment: Judgmentview is a sql server view and contains about 5 fields and the judgment field is the one encrypted.  So its returning the result to an asp:formview. The new problem now is how to return the result to the asp formview control.

Comment: @GrantWinney it will be faster by 1 function call, because first you call lambda then SomeMethodThatDecryptsView, but I guess (or hope) that compiler+JIT will be able to inline it.

Comment: Hi all who helped! The above code by Grant has worked and I am very very grateful.  I don't know how to express my joy. Thank you very much indeed. You guys are kind.